# How to decompress gzip files in Node.js

Tags: node.js, gzip

I want to unzip gzip files in Node.js I've tried [some] packages but nothing is working. Can you provide a package with sample code which can decompress gzip files in Node.js?

Comment: What packages did you tried? What were the problems or the errors? [zlib.Gunzip](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_zlib_gunzip) can do that.

Comment: can u show me the code of zlib.gunzip .because i am unable to found the example for  zlib.gunzip

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`gunzip-file`** node package worked fine!

Do:

```
npm install gunzip-file
```

Then:

```
'use strict'

const gunzip = require('gunzip-file')

// 'sitemap.xml.gz' - source file
// 'sitemap.xml'    - destination file
// () => { ... }    - notification callback
gunzip('sitemap.xml.gz', 'sitemap.xml', () => {
  console.log('gunzip done!')
})
```

Finally, run with Node at your shell.

Comment: okay  got it i was adding destination path . dnt know the desitnation path needs file name too

Comment: I've used source and destination file at project's root directory, so, in this case, the path given by Node.js environment.

Comment: note that gzip/gunzip has been part of the standard library `zlib` module since Node 0.5.8, effectively having been part of Node since day one. Installing a separate package just to do what Node can already natively do is kind of silly =)

Comment: Yes, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, recent versions of Node replace several NPM libs other days useful.

Comment: Certainly, but that's not applicable in this case: `zlib` was added to Node in v0.5.8, which was released in late 2011. That's many, _many_ years before this answer got posted. Whether it's 2012, 2017, or 2022, no third party package was (and is) necessary =)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use `zlib.Gunzip`.

Function prototype is `zlib.Gunzip(buf, callback)`. The first argument is the [raw archive data as a buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) that you want to extract, the second one is a callback which accept two arguments (result and error).

An implementation would be:

```
zlib.Gunzip(raw_data, function (error, result) {
   if (error) throw error;
   // Access data here through result as a Buffer
})
```

Comment: it says  incorrect header check
    at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:355:17)

Comment: How did you created `raw_data`?

Comment: @MalikKamranAbid Also, are you sure that the archive isn't corrupted?

Comment: yes i am sure  . i did extract it is working fine but when i do it through node.js  it is not working

Comment: Remember that an archive has a whole file system where as a gzipped stream is the compressed data. The archive may have a completely different header value and the decomp. stream may start later

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tar.gz` npm package to take care of this problem.

write following method to extract it to specific path:

```
targz().extract('/bkp/backup.tar.gz', '/home/myuser')
  .then(function(){
    console.log('Job done!');
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log('Something is wrong ', err.stack);
  });
```

For more details you can follow this [link](https://github.com/alanhoff/node-tar.gz)

Comment: Error: invalid signature: 0x8088b1f . I guess it only work for files which are in zip format

Comment: did u try this ?

Comment: This package is already deprecated and not maintained.
It should not be used.
Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using zlib.createGunzip() method. (without installing & importing any another library).

```
const fs = require("fs");
const zlib = require("zlib");

//creates gunzip obj
const gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

const input = fs.createReadStream("inputFile.gz");
const output = fs.createWriteStream("outputFile.txt");

//takes inputFile.gz as an input & extracts file as outputFile.txt
input.pipe(gunzip).pipe(output).on("finish",{
    console.log("file execution finished");
});
```